# Storage permission Issue on Android after updating to API 33

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic, Angular, and capacitor application. And I am using Cordova-diagnostic-plugin in the app. I am using it to download images on phone. and I am facing an issue After updating to Android API 33

**Current behavior:**

After updating the app to target Android API 33. When I try to download an image, it shows the Storage Request dialog stating to allow the app to access files on your device.

I have tried to request permission again for Android API 33 as you mentioned in the documentation and it doesn't open any permission dialog and shows following message in logs:

```
Requesting permission for android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
 
Requesting permissions

Notifying listeners for event pause

No listeners found for event pause

App paused

Unable to find a Capacitor plugin to handle permission requestCode, trying Cordova plugins 0
```

**Expected behavior:**

It should download and store images on the phone after clicking on the download button.

**Screenshots**

[image: wxs-screenshot]

**Environment information**

- Ionic CLI: 7.1.1
- Ionic Framework: @ionic/angular 7.2.0
- @angular/cli: 16.1.0
- @ionic/angular-toolkit: 9.0.0

Capacitor:

- Capacitor CLI      : 5.2.2
- @capacitor/android : 5.2.2
- @capacitor/core    : 5.2.2
- @capacitor/ios     : 5.2.2

System:

- NodeJS : v18.10.0
- npm    : 8.19.2
- Target Android SDK version

  - `33`
- Plugin Version

  - `"cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^7.1.2"`

**Code:**

```
const destinationUri = this.platform.is("android")
    ? "file:///storage/emulated/0/"
    : this.ionicFile.dataDirectory;

  
  const blob: Blob = res.data;

  if (this.platform.is("android")) {
    try {
      await this.ionicFile.checkDir(destinationUri, "dcim/WXS ONE");
    } catch {
      await this.ionicFile.createDir(destinationUri, "dcim/WXS ONE", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: For an Android 33 device you will not request storage permission. You have it by default. Try it and you will see.

Comment: No, It didn't work. didn't have the permission to save the file

Comment: `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` does no longer exists on API33: "Starting in API level 33, this permission has no effect." https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Where exactly did you try to save the file,? As not all storage locations are allowed. Full path of file please.

Comment: @blackapps I have updated the question with the code. Kindly check it out

Comment: You did not mention full path first.

Comment: What do you mean? The Cordova File plugin is used to store the file and this is what it requires. It is working on devices < API 33. If i am missing something, then kindly elaborate a little

Comment: I already did. So tell full path of file so we can see if you used a storage location that is allowed.

Comment: Hope [this](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem) will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Capacitor FileSystem to store the image in mobile device

Answer (score 0):

Someone already posted the correct answer, but for API 33 `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` has been depreciated. There are more granular permissions now, see [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions)